# Find <p> with biggest font

Tags: webkit, phantomjs

Say I have different `<p>` elements in my HTML document. Once rendered and depending on the applied style, some of them might have a bigger font size than the others.

How can I get the content of the `<p>` which font size is bigger than the rest using PhantomJS? Is that even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [page.evaluate](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html) to evaluates a js function in the context of the web page. To get the font size for a given element, use [Window.getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.getComputedStyle).

Finally, this could be somehting like this

```js
var page = require('webpage').create();
var url = 'http://jquery.com/';//just an example

page.open(url, function(status) {
    var results = page.evaluate(function() {
        return [].map.call(window.document.querySelectorAll('p'), function(p) { 
        return {content:p.innerHTML, size:window.getComputedStyle(p)['fontSize']}
        }).sort(function(a, b) {return b.size.replace(/px/, '')-a.size.replace(/px/, '');});
    });
    if(results && results.length>0) {
         console.log(JSON.stringify(results[0]));
    }       
    phantom.exit();
});
```